# What are some idioms for actions of sabotage that convey helplessness and frustration more than petulance or malice?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, idioms

I am thinking, for instance, about how many commentaries have framed the Brexit vote or the Trump victory as a counterintuitive and perhaps self-defeating vote by the working class in an act of sheer frustration against an establishment perceived to be repeatedly failing them. What is this act of sabotage? How does one characterise the action of those Rust Belt voters or Labour voters who threw a Molotov cocktail at the liberal establishment for it to wake up? It is surely a counterintuitive measure of the last resort because they have voted against those very parties that forge them a safety net? Is it putting "**a spoke in the wheel**" or "**a wrench in the works**" of the establishment so that it wakes up? Is it **tossing the chessboard** (?) in the face of defeat? None of these seem right to me. Are there better expressions which, while they gives a sense of deliberate sabotage, should also convey helplessness and frustration more than petulance or malice?

Comment: The title doesn't match the question in the body. If someone tosses a chessboard, they are more angry at themselves than at their opponent's victory. The question in the body contains the term "counter-intuitive" which I think many UK and US citizens thought after the election results came in. Could you try to fix this disparity in your question? Otherwise, it's a lovely question, and I'm sure many will be interested in reading users' answers. Thank you.

Comment: P.S Some users of this community think the question is too broad, and have voted to close your post. I believe this is motivated by the conflict I mentioned in my earlier comment.

Comment: You need to **fix the title**, users are like children  they see shiny things first and forget to look at the content ☺ It's +1 from me anyway because I like the Q

Comment: Oh! But if I say "a spoke in the wheel" in the title, this might be closed as a duplicate. Let me try again. :) Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why petulance doesn't work? Isn't petulance just frustration in action? Are you trying to discriminate between acts born of a sense of futility and those born of malicious intent?

Comment: Because petulance (in my own bad image of tossing the chessboard or in Malvolio's suggestion of "taking the ball and going home") suggests sulky behaviour in the face of a loss possibly caused by one's own fault, as @Mari-LouA pointed out. The kind of self-destructive forms of protest we have here are rather a last resort against a rigged system, and when all other means have been deemed exhausted. It should evoke pity rather than anger from the onlookers. That is perhaps why "acting out" and "kamikaze" are better at capturing this sentiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there better expressions which, while they gives a sense of
>   deliberate sabotage, should also convey helplessness and frustration
>   more than petulance or malice?

You could say they are [***acting out***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/act%20out). From Merriam Webster:

> ### act out
>
> *verb*
>   intransitive verb
>   :  to behave badly or in a socially unacceptable
>   often self-defeating manner especially as a means of venting painful
>   emotions (as fear or frustration)

I think this expression gets at your sense that the potentially self-destructive behavior is motivated by "helplessness and frustration" and also that it is intended, if only unconsciously, as a wake-up call or demand for attention from those who are perceived to be in power.

Other expressions that might suit include:

***desperate measures*** (called for by *desperate times*; see [Wiktionary](http://desperate_times_call_for_desperate_measures));

***cornered rat syndrome*** (this one doesn't seem to appear in standard Dictionaries, but there's a fairly good explanation in Tim Halliday's *Animal Behavior*);

or maybe ***kamikaze voting*** (I thought I had made up this phrase, but it has been used several times recently—see, e.g., the [Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/marta-andreasen/the-kamikaze-politics-of-_b_5076645.html?m=false), [Steemit](https://steemit.com/politics/@dantheman/what-would-smart-ballots-and-kamikaze-voters-mean-to-democracy), or [this reddit post](https://m.reddit.com/r/reddit.com/comments/du6du/im_pretty_progressivebut_maybe_kamikaze_voting/); [definition of *kamikaze* from MacMillan Dictionary here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/kamikaze)).

Comment: +1 for *desperate measures* . I was going to answer  *an act of desperation* but I think they're basically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

How about "take your ball and go home"?  It suggests a petulant child, ending a game he is losing.

Comment: This has been flagged as low-quality, could you add a bit more explanation to improve it?

Comment: I guess it is my bad as the OP. My question was initially titled to seek idioms for actions similar to tossing the chessboard in defeat. To that extent, @Malvolio 's answer was good.